# split and merge csv python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, visualization

I have 4 folders and every folder has like 500 CSV files. 
I want to collect all the names of the CSV files in one CSV for visualization by python.

All CSV files have just one column. How can I split to multi columns the rows like this [2016 05 30:t5-45+09], (there is no comma here and no space)

I wanna put all of the information in column like:

```
year | month | day 
2016 | 05  | 30

columns_name =['col1 ','col2','col3']
read=pd.read_csv("file path", header=None, names=columns_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list down the directories path and read all files inside them using `os.listdir()` as described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory).

As for splitting the the column into 3, first you have to iterate each rows of the csv using `csv.reader` as described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). Then for each row, convert them to 3 parts and write them back to the new csv. You can do something like this for the conversion:

```
import re

row = ['2016 05 30:t5-45+09']
res = re.search('(\d{4}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}):.*', row[0], re.IGNORECASE)
print(res.groups()) # ('2016', '05', '30')
```

You can find example on how to write them back to csv in the [same doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).